# Copiar tablas MYQL a base de datos en otro servidor

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Quiero copiar una serie de tablas mysql a otro servidor diferente de respaldo, la idea es hacer algo que se ejecute automaticamente cada 24 hs.

**Ejemplo**:

```
$dblink1=mysqli_connect('server1', 'user1', 'pass1','baseS1'); // connect server 1

$dblink2=mysqli_connect('server2', 'user2', 'pass2','baseS2'); // connect server 2
```

Son varias tablas, entre ellas una tiene mas de *200.000 registros* y hay otras de entre *40/60.000 registros*. Ambos sistemas cuentan con `MYSQL 5.7 y PHP 7.4`

¿Conviene armar algo sistematico en PHP? (estuve probando, pero con resultados no muy satisfactorios)

¿o conviene armar mysqldump (generico o para cada tabla)?

Gracias desde ya

Comment: ¿Y tu hosting no te proporciona esas copias de seguridad? Mira en el cpanel, seguro que tienes esa opción... :)

Comment: Sí, pero esto es aparte, la idea es si hubiera algun problema en este server, poder levantar el sitio en el otro, con las tablas actualizadas o casi actualizadas.

Comment: El `mysqldump` me parece lo más sencillo... Aunque, si quieres algo en tiempo real, podrías hacer las escrituras por duplicado desde PHP en ambas bases de datos y así las tendrías siempre conciliadas... En una lees y escribes; y en la otra únicamente escribes... O lees de ambas para repartir la carga

Comment: Programar un backup periódico que no quede en el mismo servidor y así poder restaurar a partir de eso. O tener un servidor secundario sincronizando... depende del presupuesto y lo crítico del asunto

Comment: mírate este enlace : https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-copiar-tablas-de-una-base-de-datos-otra-en-sql-server/